# Why no warning when changing refernce-type instance received as parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering, in C#, when you have a member that is not in used. The intellinsense/compiler warns when you it is not being used.
When passing reference-type instance of a class as parameter, changing its members will affect the instance after leaving the function.

If inside the function we replace the instance with a new one:

```
private void DoSomething(MyData data)
{
     data=new MyData(); //Why is this allowed and no even warning
}
```

the instance will remain since we cannot change the value of a references type passed on function but only the data that is pointed by it.

Why no warning on this ?
And what is the purpose of even enabling it ?

Comment: use resharper. it does warn.

Comment: `And what is the purpose of even enabling it ?`, well for one: `if (data == null) data = new MyData();`

Comment: I'm removing the `language-agnostic` tag because the question is specifically about the `C#` language

Answer (score 0):

It is *occassionally* clear and concise to "fix up" parameters that are passed to a function. The example @Rob gives `data = data ?? new MyData()`, allows a [Null Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html) pattern to be used, such that the rest of the function can be written never needing to check if `data == null`.

You could, of course, use a different variable but one some occasions the distinction between what was actually passed in vs the "fix up" value is not meaningful.